# How to get input from user and use it in CMD using DXL?

Tags: ibm-doors

Hello I have been trying to get user input and store it in a variable, and then use that variable in a CMD. ALL of this in a DXL script!
Take a glance into the code I have tried this but still not working.

```
string wheretosave = ""
DB exBox = create "Get Path"  
DBE stringInn = field(exBox, "ADD Path where to save:", "", 80)

void doGet(DB exBox) {
    wheretosave = get stringInn 
    print wheretosave "\n"    
    system("cmd.exe /C cd /d wheretosave & dir & PAUSE")
}

apply(exBox, "Get", doGet)  
show exBox
```

Answer (score 1):

to add "wheretosave" to a string, use

```
system("cmd.exe /C cd /d " wheretosave " & dir & PAUSE")
```

But I think the system call does not work. When I start a command line and do a command

```
cmd.exe /C cd /d d:\temp & dir & PAUSE
```

then I get the dir of the original directory.

@root: ADDITION: my problem was that I did not have a directory d:\temp on my PC... 
But after reading your comment, it seems the point was not understood.

To be more precise:
First: there is no interpolation in DXL. If you want to create a string which contains a) some fixed characters, b) the content of a variable (here: wheretosave) and c) some more fixed characters, you have to use a < space > to concanate the three parts. So, do it like this: `string s1 = "fixedtexta" wheretosave "fixedtextb"`.

Second: If the fixed characters contains a quotation mark then you have to escape it with a backslash. So, this example would become to  `string s2 = "fixedtexta\"" wheretosave "\"fixedtextb"` to get `fixedtexta"hello world"fixedtextb` if `wheretosave`contains `hello world`

BUT your example is even more difficult.
Third: cmd.exe /C takes only one parameter. So, if you want to do more than one command in the cmd subshell, you have to surround all the commands with enclosing quotation marks `cmd.exe /C "cmd 1 & cmd 2 & cmd 3"` The way you wrote it would have translated to

1. create a subshell which does a "cd /d", end the subshell
2. in the main shell (which is still in the original directory), do a "dir"
3. in the main shell, do a "pause"

Fourth: In DOS, if you have a quotation mark inside a string, you have to escape it with a second quotation mark.

All in all the command you are looking for is

```
string wheretosave = "d:\\temp x" // or get stringInn in your example
system("cmd.exe /C \"cd /d \"\"" wheretosave "\"\" & dir & pause\"")
```

Comment: Exactly, i also can't use it. 
It should be like this 
`system("cmd.exe /C cd /d \" wheretosave \" & dir & PAUSE")`
even though I doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Try providing the *full* path and apply Mike's correction. Using "`C:\Windows`" works as expected (for me): the cmd shows the content of my Windows folder on drive C.